# Show waiting page while server reboots

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a server and create a web interface for it, if a user presses the reboot button on the page, then the user is redirected to `reboot.php` where he is supposed to see a spinner gif till the server is reachable again and the server is getting rebooted via shell execute. If the server is reachable then i need to redirect to `main.php`

So i created the following function. The function starts with a timeout of 5 seconds, because otherwise it would instantly load `main.php` because the reboot command takes it's time.

**reboot.php**

```
    $ret = false;

    test();

    function test()
    {
        setTimeout
        (
            function()
            {
                 $ret = ping("www.google.de");
                 if ($ret === false)
                 {
                     test();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     window.location.href = "main.php";
                 }
            },
            3000
        );
    }

    function ping(url)
    {
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: url,
                success: function(result)
                {
                    alert('reply');
                    return true;
                },     
                error: function(result)
                {
                    alert('timeout/error');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3" id="mydiv">
        <div class="mydiv_inhalt">
            <h2>Rebooting...</h2>
            <p>This can take about 2 minutes.</p>
            <center>
                <div class="waiting" id="waiting" style="margin-top:30px; margin-left: 0px;">
                    <center><img class="loading_table" src="http://www.securenet.com/sites/default/files/spinner.gif" alt="spinner gif"></center>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**ajax.php**

```
$cmd        = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cmd");
if ( isset( $cmd ) && $cmd == "check_online_status" )
{
    echo "true";
}
```

In my `ajax.php` i simply return "true" if the call was successful.
However, my logic does not work, it seems that my code only tries to make one call to my `ajax.php` and then never tries again and i get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the console.

I put many alerts into my code, but they are not executed, so i guess it does not try to call `ajax.php` a second time after getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

My only idea would be to wait enough time and then redirect to `main.php`, but this is not a good solution because luck is needed, what if the time was not enough etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's summarize the issues in your code:

- you need to use `setInterval` to execute the function every x seconds
- the ajax request is asynchronous, and it should stay like that. You can't expect a return value from the callback, instead, you should act *in* the callback

The resulting code is way simpler:

```
var pingUrl = "www.google.de";
var targetUrl = "main.php";
setInterval(ping, 3000);

function ping() {
    $.ajax({
        url: pingUrl,
        success: function(result) {
            window.location.href = targetUrl;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ setInterval(ping, 2000); },8000); would first wait for 10 seconds, and then ping the server every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

@EdwardBlack fisrt you have to assing .gif image to image tag with id then in that image tag you to pass style="display:none"

```html
<img id="imgid" src="" style="display:none">
```

```js
function ping(url) {

        $.ajax({
              
                url: url,
                beforeSend : function(){
                   $('#imgid').css({'display':'block'}); //or 
                   $('#imgid').css('display', 'block');   // any one
                }, 
                success: function() {
                    alert('reply');
                    return true;
                },     
                error: function() {
                    alert('timeout/error');
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server is rebooting, usually you'll need some kind of failover IP or at least a caching proxy in front of the application server (in this case, OpenERP) to tell the user that it's down. Otherwise, while the server is offline, you'll just get a generic browser error message returned to the client, like "server not found" or similar.

In short, the best way to do this is to have another physical/virtual server sitting in front of the application server that is "always" up (or a cluster of servers that are rebooted independently), so that you always have something resolving the domain name or can fail over to a backup if the primary is down due to crashes or reboots.

Hope it helps

Comment: OP want a JS page client side that'll be loaded before the reboot, and do a ping-like request on the server to get an answer before triggered the JE redirect...

Comment: Yes, im sorry if i did not expressed me correctly but yes this is my goal. Blag is right.

Answer (score 0):

**setTimeout** runs the function only **once**

you can use **setInterval** instead of setTimeout

Comment: if you read the code you will see that he does a recursive setup of setTimeout

Comment: @Soren The beginning version of this question, it does not conatins any  recursive.

Comment: read it again:  `function test() { .... if( === false) test(); ...` -- so he is attempting to recursively setup a new timeout using function `test` if the condition is false....

Comment: Revisions 2: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/695f40c4-9fae-41ad-8a7a-820604a41500/view-source

Comment: I see your point...  It is bad style on the OPs part to change the question in such a fundamental way

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. What I have done:

- Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` to execute the `ping`-function every x seconds.
- The `$.post` function is executed asynchronously (the ajax request). That means that you cannot use a while loop as you did (except you set jQuery to make the call synchronously).
- Please don't use Umlaute (äöü) in your code. Nothing good can come of it.

---

```
var timeoutCounter = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    ping(10);
}, 5000);

function ping(maxTimeouts) {
    $.post(
        'ajax.php',
        { cmd: "check_online_status" },
        function(data, status) {
            if (status == "success") {
                window.location.href = 'main.php';
                clearInterval(interval);
            } else { 
                timeoutCounter++;

                if (timeoutCounter >= maxTimeouts) {
                    alert("Max Timeouts ("+ maxTimeouts + ") exceeded!");
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }
        }
    );  
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? Why do all answers have a downvote? OP?

Comment: I don't know, i asure you that the downvotes are not from me @sjkm.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Thanks for letting me know! The voting system is not always the best thing...

Answer (score 0):

This may help as it's the closest to a ping you can do with JS :
https://github.com/jdfreder/pingjs

Use the fallback as a recursive lunch-again part, and be careful to not redirect to quick in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ping` function needs to be synchronous: param `async: false` in ajax request.

With the async request you made, you never enter the condition `if ($ret === false)`, so the recursive call can't be made.

Also, returning a value in the `success`or `error` callbacks does not make your `ping` function returning the value you want.

You have to rewrite your `ping`function like this:

```
function ping(url)
{
    var ret = false;
    $.ajax
    (
        {
            async: false,
            url: url,
            success: function(result)
            {
                alert('reply');
                ret = true;
            },     
            error: function(result)
            {
                alert('timeout/error');
                ret = false;
            }
        }
    );
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Yes i tested it. If the ajax call fails, you are in `error` callback. When ajax ends correctly (server has finiched rebooting), you are in `success` callback so it returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return **synchronously** from the `ping` the way you do -- the return value is alway `undefined` in the test function if you check the value with a debugger. The reason is that `$.ajax` is not a synchronous call.

You should not (bad style) rely on synchronous apis when building javascript, so need to consider how to do the same using an async pattern.

For further reading, look at this question: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Rewrite your code to use a async pattern, something like this;

```
$ret = false;

function rebooted(){ console.log("Reboot complete")};
test( rebooted );

function test(okcb)
{
    setTimeout
    (
        function()
        {
             ping("www.google.de",
                 function(){ $ret=true; okcb(); },
                 function(){ test(okcb);}
             );
        },
        3000
    );
}

function ping(url, yeah, nooo)
{
    $.ajax
    (
        {
            url: url,
            success: function(result)
            {
                console.log('reply');
                yeah();
            },     
            error: function(result)
            {
                console.log('timeout/error');
                nooo();
            }
        }
    );
}
```