# Easiest way to check if a website is up in a chrome extension using JS

Tags: javascript, http, request

I am making a chrome extension, and I need to check the availability of multiple websites.

I was thinking that an HTTP request could do it, or loading an img to the server and watching the onLoad event as discussed here : [Javascript: Check if server is online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224197/javascript-check-if-server-is-online)

What method should I use ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an axios request to each site, check the status code of the response, and then add the website/status code pair to an object.

```
const serversRunning = {};

for (let server of serverList){

     const response = await axios({
             url: `{url goes here}`,
             method: "GET"
           });
     serversRunning[server] = response.status;
}
```

If response code is '200' it's running. I mean, it also depends on what you want to do with that information, but I feel like that would be the easiest that I know of.

or if you just want a list of running servers, change it to:

```
const serversRunning = [];
    
for (let server of serverList){
    
     const response = await axios({
             url: `{url goes here}`,
             method: "GET"
           });
     if (response.status == '200'){
         serversRunning.push(server);
     };
}
```

Comment: Hey Polymood, not trying to beg, but if my answer worked for you, do you want to accept it? I could use the rep (I just wanna get to 50 so I can leave comments that aren't on my own posts).