# alert clients before server (Tomcat) restart

Tags: java, node.js, spring, tomcat, server

I am running an apache Tomcat server 6 on RHEL.

The server restart is being done with a script (restart_tom.sh).
I want to alert the users that are logged in to my server before the server is restarted, so they know what happens when server is not responding.

So how can i do that?
I tried using plain javascript according to this answer but doesn't work as i want.

[Javascript: Check if server is online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224197/javascript-check-if-server-is-online)

Is there a way i could do it on my script? Do i need node.js?
or is there a better way to alert users/clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes here seeking ideas. I think one of the best ways is
either using WebSockets for your version of Tomcat or [omnifaces socket](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket)
I sticked with websockets.